# Custom operation in API Platform doesn't autowire the entity

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I'am adding custom POST operation as describe https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#recommended-method

But i each time face an error saying my action doesn't find my entity as service:

> "hydra:description": "Cannot autowire argument $user of \"App\Controller\SDK\User\UserCreateAction()\": it references class \"App\Entity\SDK\User\" but no such service exists."

Here is my action:

```
class UserCreateAction extends BaseAction
{
    private $userService;

    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function __invoke(User $user)
    {
        return $this->userService->create($user);
    }
}
```

Normally, the action should automatically recognise the $user entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not currently in any of the answers here but is posted in a comment.

@cerad [explained the right solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324576/custom-operation-in-api-platform-doesnt-autowire-the-entity#comment97376217_55324607)

> Warning: the __invoke() method parameter MUST be called $data,
> otherwise, it will not be filled correctly!

Renaming the param to `$data` did the job for me.
I could find only one reference though (feel free to add a better one):
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2184

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT (2022/29/11): Please refer to the comment of @Cerad below for the fix.**

I realised it's because of my `services.yml`.
Actually, among resources which should be available to be used as service, the `Entity/` folder was excluded:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

So I changed it, I removed the "Entity", and it works fine now:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Comment: When I first read the question I assumed that when you said entity you meant something provide by the api-platform of which I 'm not very familiar with.  Now it appears you meant an actual doctrine entity.  Entities are not services and you don't inject them.  Might need to to go over the docs more carefully.  This line might be relevant: Warning: the __invoke() method parameter MUST be called $data, otherwise, it will not be filled correctly!

Comment: @Cerad yes! You are wright. I undid my modification, change my $user var to **$data** and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange case - you are trying to create user that already exists (api platform loads it from your request uri) This is illegal operation. Remove `User $user` argument from `__invoke` and inject `Request`:

```
class UserCreateAction extends BaseAction
{
    private $userService;

    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $userFields = \json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        return $this->userService->create($userFields);
    }
}
```

To understand how it works read about `ParamConverter` in symfony. When you trying to inject entity into you controller __invoke method - api platform tries to find entity by {id} in database. This is applicable for item operations.

```
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "custom": {
 *             "method": "GET",
 *             "path": "/users/{id}",
```

Comment: I understand your point. But in API Platform doc, for the custom POST operation, they proceed like that. So, I wonder why

Comment: My bad; please refer to the comment of @Cerad at the first answer. I didn't understand the API Platform

Answer (score 0):

Just like any regular controller, make sure services can be injected :

```yaml
# symfony/config/services.yaml
    App\ApiPlatform\Controller\CreateBookPublication:
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

and

```php
<?php
// App\ApiPlatform\Controller\CreateBookPublication.php

namespace App\ApiPlatform\Controller;

use App\Entity\Book;

class CreateBookPublication
{
    private $bookPublishingHandler;

    public function __construct(BookPublishingHandler $bookPublishingHandler)
    {
        $this->bookPublishingHandler = $bookPublishingHandler;
    }

    public function __invoke(Book $data): Book
    {
        $this->bookPublishingHandler->handle($data);

        return $data;
    }
}
```